# How can i populate select box with options in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

I have this in my controller

```
$this['item'] = Cat::where('parent_id',0)->pluck('cat_title');
```

and this in view

```
 <select id="inputCat" class="form-control">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>

    {% for item in item %}
    <option value={{ item.id }}>{{ item.cat_title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

  </select>
```

It indicates in the options but doesn't show the options.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `$this['item']` contains items in the first place?

Comment: Yes it does. I have been running similar queries. With that above i can move up and down options, just that i don't see the options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are plucking `Cat` with `cat_title` so returning array will **Not** have `id` or `cat_title` as key which you are referring for `value` and `option` so, may be its causing issue

Do like this,

```php
$this['items'] = Cat::where('parent_id',0)->pluck('cat_title', 'id');
//       ^ plural [ better approach ]      id as well for value  ^
```

Returning Array;

```php
Array[
    1 => 'title'
//  ^ id   ^ your cat_title
    ....
]
```

> **this will be returned** by `pluck()` so you can see no `item.id` nor `item.cat_title` is there. its `just key and value pair`.

**So for markup please use**

---

```
<select id="inputCat" class="form-control">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    {% for key, item in items %}
        <option value={{ key }}>{{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

please try this if you find issue or it did not work, then please comment.